# Device Rotation Not Working in IOS 6 Works Well in IOS 5 am I doing anything wrong?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{


    if (appDelegate.isOrientationSupport)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }

}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    NSInteger mask = 0;
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight])
        mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
        mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
        mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown])
        mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
    return mask;
}
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: sorry I read the question wrong. this isn't a duplicate. what is isOrientationSupport

Comment: That's flag to determine rotation is on or OFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the AppDelegate:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  // iOS 6
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

in your ViewController:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: I think it is worth noting that the ViewController code must be included in every ViewController that you want to rotate.  Also, If you are using a UITabBarController, and want it to rotate, then every child ViewController without exception within that UITabBarController must implement the above mentioned methods. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html) is a great post for troubleshooting all types of issues related to device rotation.